# Flutter Camera with Android 13 : my app keeps crashing

Tags: android, flutter, camera, crash, android-13

My app keeps crashing when an Android 13 user try to launch the camera (using the package camera 0.10.1) :

```
 final cameras = await availableCameras();
 final selectedCamera = cameras.first;
```

I am getting this stack trace RuntimeException :

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:,
> request=9796, result=-1, data=Intent {
> act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to
> activity {edouard.immo/edouard.immo.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.media.EncoderProfiles$VideoProfile.getWidth()' on a null
> object reference

I well have added this permission in my manifest : READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO

I really do not know what to do :(

Comment: cameras==null ? And CAMERA permission in manifest? And you do not need those two others to take a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding uses-feature for the camera in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

`<uses-feature  android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of camera library: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109769

While we wait for the fix move `compileSdkVersion 33` to `32` in build.gradle

Comment: Thank you, but my app cannot run in compileSdkVersion 32

Answer (score 0):

Add these two permission in the androidmanifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include the full details?